# Can't boot on clean install Desktop 22.04.3 or 23.04 versions

Tags: boot, grub2, ssd

Have to preface that I'm quite new to Ubuntu and Linux as a whole, so I'm very confused on how to update parameters in the installed files.
In essence I need some ELI5.

I'll take it from the top.

- I have installed 23.04, faced no boot with the same symptoms and then downgraded to 22.04.3 on a new SSD.
- When launching Ubuntu after the initial install it asks to remove the installing device and press enter to reboot the laptop.
- I do as it asks - it loads the laptop into a black screen and nothing happens (no activity on screen, LED light is off).
- I reboot and hit F12 to get into the boot menu > Go to 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' > Ubuntu with Linux 6.2.0-26 generic > Enter > Stuck at 'Loading initial ramdisk'.
  Same for the 'recovery mode' or what it's called.
- I've tried the suggestions described in this article:
  https://devicetests.com/fix-loading-initial-ramdisk-stuck-issue-upgrading-ubuntu-18-04

I'm able to run a `IUCODE_TOOL_INITRAMFS=no` from GRUB terminal but not any sudo command, as it doesn't recognize them.
From what I understood, sudo isn't a command available in GRUB at all.

- I've then booted from USB as 'Try or Install Ubuntu' to manually edit the files on the SSD
- go to `/etc/default/intel-microcode` and can't change to `IUCODE_TOOL_INITRAMFS=no` on the SSD due to not being **root**

So:

1. what I might be doing wrong?
2. if I'm going the correct way, how do I get root while booted from USB?

Comment: You weren't specific on product (ie. server or desktop, and Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop contains 2 ISOs that use different installers).  I am aware you can incorrectly write the ISO to media so it'll boot, but fail to write the boot loader correctly at install, but you gave no details as to what product, installer was used nor how it was written. There are also some firmware (ie. box specific) issues that occur with ISOs using `ubiquity` but you didn't mention what product/installer you used.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's a Ubuntu 23.04 and 22.04 Desktop.

Comment: I'm currently struggling with 22.04 version, as my assumption 23.04 could be less stable due to being newer.

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop has two different ISOs offered at download, they use different installers; if the main one didn't install, did you try the *legacy* ISO/installer?  Did you verify the ISO being correct prior install, and how did you write the ISO to media?  Did you use a *clone* type option (ie. not use re-format options that can cause boot loader to fail to install; this is possible with `ubiquity` installer which will apply to 22.04 Desktop, or *legacy* installer on 23.04; I'm unsure if the primary installer for 23.04 sorry)

Comment: I didn't try the Legacy one. I've used BalenaEtcher to make the USB installer. I've not tried the clone option, as I might have missed it, but will try it right now. There's just so many options that I got a bit overwhelmed and tried to focus on fixing the one right in front of me.

Comment: It's possible the clone method was already used; some programs (*and I don't know BalenaEtcher sorry*) allow smart reformatting options, but these items make the ISO boot & install only on some devices, clone (sometimes called *dd-mode*) works on the most devices (best to just follow Ubuntu docs for your OS be it linux/windows/osx). You may have a device where the bootloader failed to install, others can advice better for that (boot-repair etc).

Comment: I basically followed the install suggestions from Ubuntu site.
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#8-choose-your-location
Step for step with "erase disk and install ubuntu" on step 6.